# "Class view does not exist" leading to HTTP 500 are *sometimes* triggered when starting a Docker container with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

We are running Laravel under a Docker container whose entrypoint (startup script) is the following:

```
chmod a+w -R storage \
             bootstrap/cache \
             public/img

php artisan storage:link
php artisan config:cache
php artisan horizon:publish
php artisan horizon &

/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3 -O
```

The issue is that **sometimes**, when the container starts, HTTP 500 are thrown on every single request. However, during some other deployments, the container starts normally and requests are processed as they should. Moreover, when HTTP 500 errors are thrown, it's only for a couple of minutes, and then the requests are processed normally.
When this HTTP 500 status is sent back, the following error is shown:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877
Stack trace:
172.20.0.2 -  01/Nov/2021:10:18:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
#0 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(877): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')
#1 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')
#2 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array, true)
#3 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('view', Array)
#4 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array)
#5 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1423): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('view')
#6 /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Sup...
```

When googling this error, many people pointed to a Composer autoload misconfiguration. However, in our case, restarting the container sometimes fixes the problem, so I think that this reason can be excluded. My only guess is that maybe the horizon and the php-fpm7.3 commands clash with each other through a race condition, but I don't see why they would and why that would trigger these errors.